# heroku fails to pick gradle-wrapper and correct java version

Tags: java, git, heroku, gradle

I have added `system.properties` with `java.runtime.version=1.7` and created an application in heroku to run a spring mvc war file using jetty

```
anadi$ heroku apps:create gogreen
Creating gogreen... done, stack is cedar
http://gogreen.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:gogreen.git
Git remote heroku added

anadi$ cat system.properties 
java.runtime.version=1.7

anadi$ cat Procfile 
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar build/libs/jetty-runner.jar --port $PORT build/libs/*.war
```

git shows files added to index

```
anadi$ git ls-files gradle/
gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
```

however deployment fails

1. Heroku does not pick correct JDK version
2. Heroku does not find the Gradle Main class

here's the error log from heroku

```
anadi$ git push heroku master
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 368, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (178/178), done.
Writing objects: 100% (368/368), 192.45 KiB | 52.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 368 (delta 148), reused 353 (delta 140)

-----> Gradle app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.6... done
-----> Building Gradle app...
       WARNING: The Gradle buildpack is currently in Beta.
-----> executing ./gradlew stage
       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/wrapper/GradleWrapperMain
       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
       Could not find the main class: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain. Program will exit.
 !     Failed to build app

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Gradle app

To git@heroku.com:gogreen.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:gogreen.git'
```

Comment: Make sure you `git add system.properties` to ensure that Heroku uses the right Java version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed same problem by pushing gradle wrapper files to heroku master.

Inside your gradle project run wrapper: `gradle wrapper`, which creates `gradle/` directory and `gradlew` file. Commit and push those together with your code and then it should start working.

If `wrapper` task is not found add the following to the `build.gradle`

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.6'
}
```

On `git push heroku master` you should see `Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip` in the console log, like this:

```
-----> Gradle app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.7... done
-----> Building Gradle app...
       WARNING: The Gradle buildpack is currently in Beta.
-----> executing ./gradlew stage
       Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip
       ................................................
```